# $A(\phi\phi^*\gamma \gamma)$ with Spinor Helicity Formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, s-matrix-theory, helicity

I am calculating $A_4(\phi\phi^*\gamma\gamma)$ with the spinor helicity formalism ([Exercise 2.16](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697)). I am following the conventions defined in [Elvang's notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697)

Such computation requires three diagrams, two of them come from the exchange of the photons, and the third corresponds to the contact term, also known as "seagull" term.

Considering massless particles and applying transversality conditions, I obtain the following expression

$$
iA_4(\phi\phi^*\gamma\gamma)=\dfrac{4ie^2}{2p_1\cdot p_3} \epsilon_3\cdot p_2\epsilon_4\cdot p_1 + (3\leftrightarrow 4)
$$

***Obs:*** We could reach the same result if we would have considered the following exchange $(1\leftrightarrow 2) $

Where I have omitted the seagull term since it does not contribute according to [Exercise 2.15](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697).

Applying the aforementioned formalism, I have with spinor variables the following
$$
A_4(\phi\phi^*\gamma^+\gamma^-)\sim \dfrac{2}{\langle 23\rangle\lbrack 23\rbrack}\dfrac{\langle q_3|2|3\rbrack}{\langle q_33\rangle}\dfrac{\langle 4|1|q_4\rbrack}{\lbrack q_44\rbrack} + (1\leftrightarrow 2)
$$

Which could be brought to the following form

$$
\dfrac{\langle q_32\rangle\langle 41\rangle\lbrack 1q_4\rbrack}{\langle23\rangle\langle q_33\rangle\lbrack q_44\rbrack}+(1\leftrightarrow 2)\\
=\dfrac{\langle q_32\rangle\langle 41\rangle\lbrack 1q_4\rbrack}{\langle23\rangle\langle q_33\rangle\lbrack q_44\rbrack}+
\dfrac{\langle q_31\rangle\langle 42\rangle\lbrack 2q_4\rbrack}{\langle13\rangle\langle q_33\rangle\lbrack q_44\rbrack}
$$

This is expected to yield up to some phase factor [Exercise 3.4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697)

$$
A_4(\phi\phi^*\gamma^+\gamma^-)=g^2\dfrac{\langle 14\rangle\langle 24\rangle}{\langle 13\rangle\langle 23\rangle}
$$

I managed to find it by choosing allowed values for $q_3,q_4$. I am intending to reproduce the desired result without making any specific choice of the reference spinors $q_3,q_4$. Nevertheless, my work has become somehow cumbersome (i.e. applying momentum conservation, Fierz and Schouten identities) and I have the feeling that I am not getting any closer to my objective. I would appreciate any advice or suggestion on approaching this computation. I don't know if I should have considered the seagull term.